# Fetch users in workflow definition

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1CE with kaleo workflow.

I am created a new workflow definition,by editing singlelevel workflow.xml.

In my workflow definition,i had add a new transition "reference" and a task for the same.

In my reference task,i have to select a user from all users to send the reference.

How can i fetch the users..? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you task is doing, but yeah, you could definitely access to portal service class by using groovy scripts. something like:

```
<task>
    <name>Some task</name>
    <actions>
        <action>
            <name>task action</name>
            <script><![CDATA[
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import java.util.List
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;


long companyId = GetterUtil.getLong((String)
workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID));
ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext)
workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_SERVICE_CONTEXT);
List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(start, end);

]]></script>
            <script-language>groovy</script-language>
            <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
        </action>
    </actions>
    <assignments>
        <roles>
            <role>
                <role-type>regular</role-type>
                <name>Administrator</name>
            </role>
        </roles>
    </assignments>
    <transitions>
        <transition>
            <name>next</name>
            <target>Next Task</target>
        </transition>
    </transitions>
</task>
```

and you could access to you workflow task in code use WorkflowInstanceManagerUtil and WorkflowTaskManagerUtil, I hope this helps, let me know if you have further questions